# how to batch rename files while coping?

Tags: nautilus, copy

I've a lot of folder icons for movies i wanted to transfer those folder icons to a USB drive so that my friend could use those. but the problem is all of these folder icons are named "folder.png", nautilus gives the option to rename the file but i'll have to manually do that for each file, which is sort of impossible to do.

so is their a way i can transfer all these files and have them renamed automatically like "folder1.png" "folder2.png" and so on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is this really amazing app called Krename. that worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install krename
```

Answer (score 5):

`cp` can do numbered back-up copies:

```
$ cp --backup=numbered folder.png folder.png folder.png folder.png foo
$ ls foo
folder.png  folder.png.~1~  folder.png.~2~  folder.png.~3~
```

Now, just rename these:

```
$ rename -n 's/(.png).~(\d+)\~/$2$1/' foo/*
rename(foo/folder.png.~1~, foo/folder1.png)
rename(foo/folder.png.~2~, foo/folder2.png)
rename(foo/folder.png.~3~, foo/folder3.png)
```

The `-n` means that changes will be reported, but not actually performed. Run without the `-n` after verifying the output.

Comment: do i need to run it exactly like this in terminal? or i need to make some changes? (complete beginner)

Comment: You'll have to adapt to your use. For example, in the first command I'm copying the same file four times, you'll only copy it once. And `foo` will be the directory you want to copy to, so change that in both commands.